# In rails how to define custom form tags like `md-checkbox` for `checkbox`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to use Angular Material with ruby on rails. In Angular Material, we heavily use custom html tags. For example, for checkbox, we use `<md-checkbox>`. In rails when we call `f.check_box` it generates the standard html tag. How to add a custom tag for this?

Comment: Have you looked at [`content_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)? I believe that's the only way to create custom tags, but I'm not sure about using them in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you make a custom form builder to manage this better (you can of course also use `content_tag` if it's just a few places you need custom HTML tags).

Try add this to `app/helpers/angular_form_helper.rb`:

```
module AngularFormHelper
  class FormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    def check_box(method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0", &block)
      Tags::MdCheckBox.new(@object_name, method, @template, checked_value, unchecked_value, objectify_options(options)).render(&block)
    end

    def submit(value=nil, options={})
      value, options = nil, value if value.is_a?(Hash)
      value ||= submit_default_value
      @template.angular_button_tag(value, options)
    end
  end

  module Tags
    class Base < ActionView::Helpers::Tags::Base
      def add_default_name_and_id(options)
        super(options)
        options["ng-model"] = options["name"]
        options.delete("name")
      end
    end

    class MdCheckBox < Base
      def initialize(object_name, method_name, template_object, checked_value, unchecked_value, options)
        @checked_value   = checked_value
        @unchecked_value = unchecked_value
        super(object_name, method_name, template_object, options)
      end

      def render(content = nil, &block)
        options = @options.stringify_keys
        options["ng-true-value"]    = @checked_value
        options["ng-false-value"]   = @unchecked_value

        add_default_name_and_id(options)

        content = block_given? ? @template_object.capture { yield || "" } : ""

        content_tag("md-checkbox", content, options)
      end
    end
  end

  def angular_button_tag(content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
    if content_or_options.is_a? Hash
      options = content_or_options
    else
      options ||= {}
    end

    options = { 'type' => 'submit' }.merge!(options.stringify_keys)

    if block_given?
      content_tag "md-button", options, &block
    else
      content_tag "md-button", content_or_options || 'Button', options
    end
  end

  def angular_form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &block)
    options = args.extract_options!.symbolize_keys
    options[:html] = {} unless options[:html].present?
    options[:html]["ng-submit"] = options.delete(:submit)
    options[:url] = "#"
    form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *(args << options.merge(builder: FormBuilder)), &block)
  end
end
```

Then build the form with this:

```
<%= angular_form_for @resource, submit: "submit()" do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box(:field1) do %>
        Field 1
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It will produce something like this:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" class="edit_resource" id="edit_resource_1" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    ...
    <md-checkbox ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" id="resource_field1" ng-model="resource[field1]">
        Field 1
    </md-checkbox>
    <md-button type="submit">Update Resource</md-button>
</form>
```

Comment: It generates the custom tag but the problem is, when we submit the form the data won't be added to the params

Comment: I assume you want to submit with angular js handling. Updated the code, it was missing a lot of attributes. Let me know if it works for you.